# How do data joins and mutations in d3.js work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I am curious how data joins and mutations work in d3.js. For graphing there are many different ways to portray data, in some each element in the data has a direct impact on how the other data is portrayed, for example a treemap. Other graphs like a bar have data that is more independent.

My question is when what happens when we update the current nodes in d3.js. For a treemap would be re-calculating the size and shape of every node for every piece of data that is updated? or do we re-calculate the size and shape of all the nodes once all the elements are updated.

I am curious because my treemap seems to be really slow when I try to update all nodes, but much more efficient when i just remove the chart and draw it again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here -- you've framed this as a very general question (that would be answered by several tutorials), but there's also a specific case that you're interested in. If you could tell us more about this specific case, we may be able to help you with it.